# How to swap views in angularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create an angular application.
When the index.html page is loaded 2 links login and register are displayed.
When either login or register is clicked the entire view is replaced by the corresponding view.

**1.** Register/Login links should stay at the top and the corresponding view should be displayed below after clicking on them.

**2.** After successful authentication in login controller, The complete view including the login and register link should be replaced with menu-auth.html view.

I have tried using the below code, but still the 2 links disappear and login/register views appear.

Also after the http Post is fired in login controller, the menu-auth.html is displayed but appropriate css is not displayd, so I am not able to click the menu links.

I guess the menu-auth.html view is not placed in the view of index.html

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

   <head>
     <script src = "js/angular.min.js"></script> 
      <script src = "js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "app/app.js"></script>
      <script src = "controller/login.js"></script>
      <script src = "controller/register.js"></script>
      <script src = "app/config.js"></script> 

      <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="app">

      <ui-view>

      </ui-view>

      </div>
      </div>
      </body>

</html>
```

I have two views
**menu-unauth.html**

```
<a ui-sref="login" ui-sref-active="active">Login</a>
<a ui-sref="register" ui-sref-active="active">Register</a>
<ui-view="unauth"></ui-view>
```

**menu-auth.html**

```
 <a ui-sref=".nentry" ui-sref-active="active">Create Entry</a></br>
<a ui-sref=".ventry" ui-sref-active="active">View entry</a></br>  
<a ui-sref=".logout" ui-sref-active="active">Logout</a></br>

<ui-view="auth"></ui-view>
```

**config.js**

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

   $stateProvider
  .state('unauth', {  
        url:'',
        templateUrl: 'view/menu-unauth.html'   
  }) 

   .state('unauth.login', {  
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
        controller: 'login'     
  })

  .state('unauth.register', {  
        url:'/register',
        templateUrl: 'view/register.html',
        controller:'register'       
  }) 

  .state('auth', {  
        url:'/menu',
        templateUrl: 'view/menu-auth.html'   
  }) 

}]);
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router','ngCookies']);
```

**login.js (Controller)**

```
app.controller('login', function($scope,$http,$cookieStore,$state){

   $scope.login=function(){ 

   $scope.credentials={
UserName:$scope.email,
Password:$scope.password
};

   $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'test.com/sess',
    data: $scope.credentials
}).then(function(response) { 
            $state.go('auth');
    } 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to **(observe the ui-sref value changed to contain . dot)**

**menu-unauth.html**

```
<a ui-sref=".login" ui-sref-active="active">Login</a>
<a ui-sref=".register" ui-sref-active="active">Register</a>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

**config.js**

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

   $stateProvider
  .state('unauth', {  
        url:'',
        templateUrl: 'view/menu-unauth.html'   
  }) 

   .state('unauth.login', {  
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl: 'view/login.html'   
  })

  .state('unauth.register', {  
        url:'/register',
        templateUrl: 'view/register.html'   
  }) 
}]);
```